# Is there any way to set auto focus with ARCore camera?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, augmented-reality, arcore

I am working on an application where I need to put object using ARCore. And then I need to save the frames as an image.

So is there any way to set auto focus for ARCore camera?

Comment: i need to use camera autofocus with arcore camera. but arcore camera doesn't provide anything for focus. so i thought we can use the hardware camera to set the autofocus. so to get the camera instance we need to use Camera.open() or CameraManager.Open() depending on the api version. if i open the connection with camera using camera1 or camera 2 api, ARCore loses the context. and to set focus the preview has to be in foreground so does anyone know an alternative to get an instance of the camera lens ?

Comment: Like the initial releases of ARKit, ARCore doesn't seem to support autofocus just yet: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/issues/49. However, ARKit 1.5 coming out this spring does support it, so ARCore should eventually add support.

Answer (score 13):

As of ARCore 1.4, you can enable or disable autofocus through your ARCore Session's Config:

```
Session session = new Session(context);
Config config = new Config(session);
if (enableAutoFocus) {
  config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
} else {
  config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.FIXED);
}
session.configure(config);
```

https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Config.html#setFocusMode(com.google.ar.core.Config.FocusMode)

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work.. Can you post a video link showcasing the functionality?

Comment: This code is roughly the same as the example ARCore applications provided by google. Have you tried building and running the sample applications? https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/blob/a87eded256510dff6067283e522c368a3c2694ad/samples/computervision_java/app/src/main/java/com/google/ar/core/examples/java/computervision/ComputerVisionActivity.java#L379

Comment: All examples save for `ComputerVision`. This piece of code apparently, is only in this example. I'll try it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what Google ARCore engineers say about `Config.FocusMode`:

```
public static final enum Config.FocusMode
```

> `Config.FocusMode` enum selects the desired behaviour of the camera focus subsystem. Currently, the default focus mode is `FIXED`, but this default might change in the future. Note, on devices where ARCore does not support Auto Focus due to the use of a fixed focus camera, setting `AUTO` will be ignored. See the ARCore Supported Devices page for a list of affected devices.
>
> For optimal AR tracking performance, use the focus mode provided by the default session config. While capturing pictures or video, use `AUTO`. For optimal AR tracking, revert to the default focus mode once auto focus behavior is no longer needed. If your app requires fixed focus camera, call `setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode)(FIXED)` before enabling the AR session. This will ensure that your app always uses fixed focus, even if the default camera config focus mode changes in a future release.

There are two values:

```
public static final Config.FocusMode AUTO
public static final Config.FocusMode FIXED
```

So, in Java code:

```
Config ar_session_config = session.getConfig();
ar_session_config.setFocusMode(Config.FocusMode.AUTO);
session.configure(ar_session_config);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I thought I'd update the answer with implementation in `Sceneform`. Sceneform SDK 1.4 added the ability to setup autofocus. I use an extension function to enable it.

Declare the relevant fields globally.

```
//The AR Core session
private var arSession: Session? = null
private var arConfig: Config? = null
```

and the extension function definition :

```
private fun Session.setupAutofocus() {

        //Create the config
        arConfig = Config(this)

        //Check if the configuration is set to fixed
        if (arConfig?.focusMode == Config.FocusMode.FIXED)
            arConfig?.focusMode = Config.FocusMode.AUTO

        //Sceneform requires that the ARCore session is configured to the UpdateMode LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE. 
        //This is probably not required for just auto focus. I was updating the camera configuration as well
        arConfig?.updateMode = Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE

        //Reconfigure the session
        configure(arConfig)

        //Setup the session with ARSceneView
        fragment.arSceneView.setupSession(this)

        //log out if the camera is in auto focus mode
        ARApplication.log("The camera is current in focus mode : ${config.focusMode.name}")
}
```

and a good place to call this is your activity's `onResume`

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    //Check if ARSession is null. If it is, instantiate it
    if(arSession == null) {
        arSession = Session(this@EdgeActivity)
        arSession?.setupAutofocus()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is in a Unity project, then change the **CameraFocusMode** parameter to **Auto** instead of **Fixed**.

[image: Unity ARCoreConfig file settings]

Comment: How did you get this option?  What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Unity version: 2018.3
For ARCore unity package, refer [here](https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-unity-sdk/releases)