# ARCore SceneForm Camera blur

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I am working on Google ARCore. I noticed when I open my app it is showing blur everywhere. I have tried many times but still the camera is in blur, can you have any solution to fix it?

Comment: In ARCore, [Config.FocusMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48913197/is-there-any-way-to-set-auto-focus-with-arcore-camera/55566346#55566346) is responsible for defocusing.

Comment: set the camera config to the highest resolution